# c++ Overloading == for complex numbers

Tags: operator-overloading

I am attempting to overload the == operator then test it with the code in the main function. It gives me an error and says the z in my if statement must be a bool type or converted into one. I am just wondering where I am going wrong here and how to go about setting that part up. Here is the code snippet. I declared double real & double imaginary as private variables also.

```
Complex Complex::operator==(const Complex &operand2) const
{
if (real == operand2.real, imaginary == operand2.imaginary)
    return true;
else
    return false;
}
int main()
{   
Complex x(1, 2);
Complex y(2, 3);
Complex z, w, v;

z = x + y;
w = x – y;

if (z == w)
    cout << " z = w" << endl;
else
    cout << " z != w" << endl;

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code will be something like this :

```
bool Complex::operator==(const Complex &operand2) const
{
    return (real == operand2.real && imaginary == operand2.imaginary) ;
}
```

1. The return type should be `bool` as the result is always `true` or `false`.
2. Since both the real and imaginary parts need to be equal, you use `&&` (AND) operation to join the two conditions.

Also notice that any operation involving the `==` operator will return a `bool` value (either `true` or `false`) and hence instead of a `if` condition, you can directly return the result.

Comment: ah yeah what a dumb mistake, completely slipped my mind on the return type, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your return a `bool` from your operator ,so what else do you expect

Answer (score 0):

If you defined operator return value as complex you cannot return boolean.

```
Complex Complex::operator==/*...*/
```

This actually returns the `Complex` type which is not problem, unless you need bool value.

```
bool Complex::operator==
```

So return type here is what you want. For further information read this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators